# How to run multiptle queries postgresql statements from C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am using EntityFramework and code migrations to keep my Postgres database up to date.
Before deployment on a new environment I would like to make sure the database exists and that the user that will execute queries for the application has enough permissions to do this.
So in short I would like to do the following from my Migrations project before running `context.Database.Migrate()`:

- Check whether the database exists
- If it doesn't exist create it
- Create the user if it doesn't exists
- Grant permissions to the user
- Run migrations

I have two options (I think):

1. Run multiple statements at once, keeping the logic inside the query itself and avoid having it in code (C#)
2. Run statements and deciding in code what to do next.

Option 1 has my preference but when I run the statement checking whether the database exists and create it if it doesn't I get an error: `CREATE DATABASE cannot be executed from a function`.
The query I'm running looks like this:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datname='database_name') THEN
        CREATE DATABASE database_name;
    END IF;
END
$$
```

Option 2 would involve running the statement to check if the database exists with the following code:

```
using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection("connection"))
{
    conn.Open();
    var sql = "SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname='database_name'";
    var command = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
    var dbExists = command.ExecuteScalar();
    
    if(dbExists == null)
    {
        command = new NpgsqlCommand("CREATE DATABASE database_name", conn);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

The above code works but I think I prefer option 1.

So I have 2 questions:

1. How can I fix the `CREATE DATABASE cannot be executed from a function` error.
2. Is the second option considered 'wrong'?

Comment: create database is special statement which cannot be executed inside a transaction block, so you need to remove the "DO ..." block.

Comment: This:
`IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datname='database_name') THEN
        CREATE DATABASE database_name;
END IF;`
Results in `syntax error at or near IF`

Comment: Well yes, it can only be run without IF, unless you want to use some workarounds... I'd say just stick with your option 2 for creating database, there is nothing wrong with it. Postgres doesn't have a syntax to create database if it not exists, and doesn't allow to create it inside a block.